# How would I make my google maps app start with zoom on my current location

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

How would I make my google maps app on android start with zoom on my current location without pressing or doing anything?

edit. problem solved

```
Criteria cri= new Criteria();
    String bbb = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cri, true);
    Location myLocation = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(bbb);

    double lat= myLocation.getLatitude();
    double long = myLocation.getLongitude();
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, long);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 20));
```

Comment: sc = new LatLng(flati,flongi);  CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sc,20); replace the flati and flongi  with your latitude and longitude

Comment: add this forgot about it  mMap.moveCamera(update);

Comment: check this http://raghunandankavi.blogspot.in/2013/04/google-map-api-v2.html and part 1 http://raghunandankavi.blogspot.in/2013/04/google-map-api-v2-on-android.html.

Comment: the part 2 shows how to get latitude and longitude of your current location using gps. So in onStart() of you activity you check if gps is enabled or not. If no prompt the user to enable. get the latitude and longitude of your current location using location manager. Once you get the co-ordinates you can put a marker and zoom your camera to the co-ordinates

Comment: Denn - post your edit as an answer and mark it as correct - i'll upvote you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved

```
Criteria cri= new Criteria();
String bbb = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cri, true);
Location myLocation = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(bbb);

double lat= myLocation.getLatitude();
double long = myLocation.getLongitude();
LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, long);

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it this way

```
CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,long));
CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5);

map.moveCamera(center);
map.animateCamera(zoom);
```

Comment: there are some programmatic ways of doing this too, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756261/how-to-get-the-current-lcoation-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/13830598#13830598

Comment: but how i put in lat / long mu current location?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742551/how-to-get-my-location-changed-event-with-google-maps-android-api-v2/14305851#14305851 for how to get your current location