# android google maps show current location; map not showing

Tags: android, google-maps

I've been following this tutorial [Showing current location in Google Maps using API v2](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/) but whatever I do, my map just doesn't show. Screen is all grey, except the buttons for zooming. I have added permissions for the internet, I've generated API key (v2) a dozen of times (I am selecting "create new Android key..." and entering SHA1 certificate fingerprint and it generates fine), my GPS is enabled... I don't know what to do anymore. Here's my code & manifest:

```
package com.example.myexample;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ 
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();
        }

        else { 

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();
            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 
            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location); 
        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
        tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );
    }

@Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.myexample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myexample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myexample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my api"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: do you get exceptions or errors?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752015/how-would-i-make-my-google-maps-app-start-with-zoom-on-my-current-location/16752081#16752081

Comment: there is a bug with setMyLocationEnabled(true); - it always returns nil

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes I've just seen that I get 2 errors:
"error opening trace file: no such file or directory" and
"Google Maps Android API v2 only suppports deviceswith OpenGL ES 2.0 and above"

Comment: do you test it on a device or emulator?

Comment: I am testing it on an emulator

Comment: you should test it on a device for exactly "only suppports deviceswith OpenGL ES 2.0 " this reason. try it on device and check

Comment: Ok, I have. It does show my coordinates correctly at the top, but the map still doesn't show.

Comment: Most likely wrong API key. Check for logs from map api, they are usually self explanatory.

Comment: Wrong how? I am doing it according to instructions in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
and it does generate. It starts with "AIza...". I don't get any errors/messages concerning the key.

Answer (score 0):

try this code , hope this will help

MainActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

its xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/googleMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_above="@+id/latlongLocation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latlongLocation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ff058fff"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```