# Google+ PlusClient getCurrentLocation() method

Tags: android, google-plus

I see that the Person object that can be retrieved from the loadPerson method of PlusClient has a getCurrentLocation() method. For some reason I do not see the getCurrentLocation() method in the documentation online. Also, when I try to use it, it returns null always. What's the deal with this function?

Comment: it's a known bug. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742551/how-to-get-my-location-changed-event-with-google-maps-android-api-v2/14305851#14305851 for how to get current location in android

Comment: Rachel, not exactly what I was thinking. I dont wan't to get my own location, I want to get someone elses that I have loaded with mPlusClient.loadPeople().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getCurrentLocation is documented under the Person object:

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html#getCurrentLocation()

It returns the users current location if they have set it to a value on their Google+ profile.  It will return null if they have not set it to a value.

Comment: Hey, are you sure? I have a few friends who have locations set as do I but the method always returns `null` I'm guessing it's not actually wired up to anything yet.

Comment: Have you set your location to be publicly visible?  It will only be returned if you have made it public.

Comment: No, who would? It needs to contain the value for people who have shared their location with the authenticated user. If not, it's pointless.

Answer (score 0):

So I hate to be the bearer of bad news on this one, but it seems like Google+ has stopped support for the getCurrentLocation part of their People api. There's a whole thread [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=620) about complaints concerning it.

EDIT: Figured out a workaround to the problem. I guess they just put everything in the getplaceslived method.

```
String location = "";
for(PlacesLived place : Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient).getPlacesLived()){
        //If the place is primary, record it and break
        if(place.isPrimary()){
            location = place.getValue();
            break;
        }
        //If it isn't and there isn't any location yet, record the most recent location and wait to see if another is primary
        if(location.equals("")){
            location = place.getValue();
        }
    }
```