# How works the method PlusClient getCurrentLocation()?

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm trying recover the location of the class PlusClient, but this method always returns NULL.
In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753417/google-plusclient-getcurrentlocation-method) the user Lee say:

> Have you set your location to be publicly visible? It will only be
>   returned if you have made it public.

But I tested with the location public and continues return NULL, I try get my location too, and the return is NULL too.

Below my code:

```
    public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult status, PersonBuffer personBuffer,
        String nextPageToken) {
    switch (status.getErrorCode()) {
        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
            mListItems.clear();
            try {
                int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    mListItems.add(personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName()+"\n"+
                            ((personBuffer.get(i).hasCurrentLocation()) ? 
                                    personBuffer.get(i).getCurrentLocation() :
                            "Value NULL"));                                                                         
                }
            } finally {
                personBuffer.close();
            }

            mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;

        case ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED:
            Log.d(TAG, "Reconectando");
            mPlusClient.disconnect();
            mPlusClient.connect();
            break;

        default:
            Log.e(TAG, "Error when listing people: " + status);
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm doing anything wrong?