# android googleMaps api v2 arrow not centered by moving

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working with Google Maps V2 and i want that the blue arrow is always centered on the map when i was driving/moving. But it remains for a 3-4 seconds on the spot and then jumps suddenly to the center. If i drive fast, the arrow is even in the few seconds out of the map and jumps then to the center. What i am doing wrong in the code?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
....

//when button is clicked
public void initStart() {
    initMap();
    initLocation();
}

 public void initMap() {
    supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);

    myMap = supportmapfragment.getMap();
    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    myMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
    myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
}


  public void initLocation() {
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if(provider != null ) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);  
}

  ....

  @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

 if(location != null) {

 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
 myMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17));
 }
}
```

Does anyone have a counsel? thanks in advance

PS: sry for my english (its not good) :)

Comment: Have a look at this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14305851/2045570

Comment: yes, but that is the new api or not?? i am not using the new api yet. i have to work it with the older api. my problem is only the marker/arrow by driving, to hold it in the center of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of LocationManager use GoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener, which notifies you when the position of blue dot is changed.

Comment: Hi Maciej, so I should not use the locationmanager?? can you tell me how and where exactly should I use the GoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener? I'm honestly a little confused.